# MySQL backups MyISAM vs. InnoDB

Tags: mysql

I have a django project that uses `MyISAM` tables. When I perform a backup, I have heard that it is recommended to use `InnoDB` tables rather than the `MyISAM`. What is the reason why this is suggested and is it imperative that I use `InnoDB` for backup?

Currently, I'm using the following for backup:

```
mysqldump -v -u $USER --password=$PASSWORD $DB >$BACKUP_FOLDER/$BACKUP_FILENAME
```

How would I convert this to `InnoDB` and do a backup?

Comment: Did none of the sources that recommended InnoDB include any explanation as to why it should be preferred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommendation is more for data security - MyISAM tables are known to be less tolerant to faults (ie machine crashes etc)

To change the table types you would have to take you app offline and use ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE=InnoDB;

With large tables you need at least twice as much disk space and it is possible to take many days if you are talking 100's millions of rows

Note there may be performance decrease in your application after and there still can be issues because it obviously wasnt designed to use transactions.

Comment: What does "because it obviously wasnt designed to use transactions" mean?

Comment: The application. Inserting a 10,000 rows is suddenly going to be much slower because each will be inserted in a transaction. Retrofitting code with transactional support could be hard - because you have to research where transactional boundaries actually are.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  Wasn't sure if you were talking about the application or the storage engine.